# Использование свойства переменной при цепочке вызовов

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, node.js

Как нужно объявить объекты чтобы следующий код был работоспособен?
(чтобы переменная product имела свойства, а не была undefined)

```
var product = Factory.createProduct().sale(function() {
  console.log(product.id) 
});
```

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: на момент вызова `sale`, ссылка на  `product` еще undefined. Это очевидно. Т.е. сначала вы должны откуда-то вернуть ссылку на `product`.

Comment: @Sublihim с точки зрения программы product может быть определен если sale что-то возвращает, а вызов callback происходит после того, как работа sale завершена. А в остальном остается только гадать, что там у автора и как.

Comment: это я понимаю, но мне не очень ясно почему, к примеру [такой](https://github.com/Automattic/kue/blame/master/Readme.md#L91) код работает и в какой момент переменной `job` присваивается значение

Comment: @OlmerDale интересно, как вы вызовете callback после return?

Comment: @Sublihim я даже не знаю что сказать, вариантов просто очень много и каждый из них обычное дело для js. То есть этот вопрос вообще самые самые основы языка. А автору я даже не знаю что посоветовать. Мне не хочется ходить по ссылкам и разбираться в чужом коде, чтобы потом объяснять то что написано во всех книгах. А по показанному коду можно только гадать... Поэтому на мой взгляд сложная ситуация в которой сможет помочь только не я.

Comment: @OlmerDale, так и набросали бы ответ, для задающего вопрос) Рассказали бы про замыкания )

Comment: @Sublihim какой ответ если я уже два раза повторил что можно только гадать?

Comment: @OlmerDale показали бы, на основе подобной конструкции, как можно присвоить значение product

Comment: @Владимир, по указанной ссылке - readme, если пойти посмотреть код указанных функций (например [save](https://github.com/Automattic/kue/blob/master/lib/queue/job.js#L782)) все сразу станет понятно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приведу один из примеров.
Давайте упростим пример, чтобы было понятней:

```js
function sale(callback) {
  if (callback) {
    setTimeout(callback, 100);
  }
  return {
    id: 'some_id'
  };
};


var product = sale(function() {
  console.log('in callback: ' + product.id);
});

console.log('simple log: ' + product.id);
```

Здесь в функцию `sale` был передан объект функции, который как бы "захватил" область выполнения, которая содержит `product`. Это называется - замыкание.

В итоге - было присвоено значение `product`, а после этого выполнился по таймауту callback, который содержал в себе ссылку на `product`

Comment: вместо `setTimeout` может быть _любая_ асинхронная функция, либо событие

Comment: да, timeout, я привел, как самый доступный пример